# Wordpress, не обновляется счетчик меток

Tags: php, wordpress

При обновлении записи к посту добавляются все метки, однако количество записей у метки "обнуляется". Однако если просто обновить запись через админку вордпресса - все "срабатывает" как надо.

При публикации поста через `wp_insert_post` метки добавляются и у метки увеличивается количество постов, но после `wp_update_post` метки у записи остаются, но у метки теряется связь с постом, при этом при просмотре архива по метке все отображается корерктно, но если отбирать метки через `get_tags` то вывод идет без нужного результата.

Не помогает ни этот метод:

```
$directory = array( 'ID' => $directory_post_id, 'post_type' => $directory_category, 'tax_input' => array( 'post_tag' => $directory_tags ));
$directory_post = wp_update_post($directory);
```

ни этот метод:

```
wp_set_post_terms( $directory_post_id, $directory_tags, 'post_tag',
false );
```

Используется несколько `register_post_type`, ко всем привязаны метки `'taxonomies' =>   array('post_tag')`

Comment: Надо скидывать кеш

Comment: @mihdan, как возможно это сделать без участия плагинов?